# partail View Form Submit using Ajax in mvc 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Can Somebody kindly add Simple Example for Partial View from submit using Ajax in MVC 4.I have done lot of searching on google but unfortunately I couldn't able to find Simple example for understand about coding. I want to Add comment box in parent View as partail view form.[This is what I have done up to now](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37979075/ajax-partial-view-doesnt-submit-data-to-db-in-mvc-4)

I want to use one model for parent View and another model for partail View. If there another Idea to do that kindly tell me the way to do that.because I'm new to mvc4 & still studying about it.

Answer (score 0):

There are many examples available in sites.
Your can use this link.
    http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/3d39b4/working-with-html-beginform-and-ajax-beginform-in-mvc-3/
Or this http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/script/using-ajax-beginform-with-asp-net-mvc

It shows both HTML.BeginFirm and Ajax.Beginform examples for form submission.
And as far as you want to use different model for partial views;then see the sample code

```
 public class ParentModel{
 public ChildModel1 childObj1;

public ChildModel2 childObj2;
}
public class ChildModel1{
public int prop1;
public string prop2;}
}
public class ChildModel2{
public int prop3;
public string prp4;}
}
```

Then use ParentModel as your ViewModel.

Comment: I can do ajax for Simple View.when It comes to partail View I doesn't work. that is my problem. I have done lot of Googling but nothing worked for me.

Comment: Are you including the reference files need to run ajax in .NET